# Does Swift Strike get enhanced in Dragonblade?

Tags: overwatch

When Genji is using Dragonblade I can also use [Swift Strike](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Genji#Swift_Strike); if I Swift Strike enemies while wielding the Dragonblade, they seem to die instantly.

Does Swift Strike deal more damage during Genji's ult? Or is it because I automatically slash after the Swift Strike?

Answer (score 3):

> Swift Strike: Genji darts forward, slashing with his katana and passing through foes in his path. If Genji eliminates a target, he can instantly use this ability again. (Damage: 50)
>
> Dragonblade: Genji brandishes his Ōdachi for a brief period of time. Until he sheathes his sword, Genji can deliver killing strikes to any targets within his reach. (Damage: 120 per slash)

As can be seen from above, Swift Strike only deals a fixed amount of damage (50). In addition, if I am not wrong, Genji uses different weapons for Dragonblade and Swift Strike so it can't be possible that you will slash as you dash.

The reason why you are killing enemies instantly is most likely because they are low enough that you can just dash once/slash once and its enough to kill them.

Source: The game itself

Comment: Worth adding the source for that? For scientific completeness :)

Comment: @KizTrap Those are the official descriptions in-game

Comment: Although I think you're probably right, I don't find those descriptions remotely convincing. Just because Swift Strike normally does 50 damage doesn't mean it doesn't do more when you have Dragonblade active.

Comment: If you don't believe it, go training range and test it. As someone with 72 hours on Genji I can assure you using your ult does not increase your swift strike damage.